How to get accurate reading from clip on candy thermometer?
I am new to candy making and I bought a clip on candy thermometer.
I noticed while using it that the side of pot and content is always a bit cooler than the center of the pot. I was making candy in a Dutch oven where the center of the pot was 20 degrees hotter than the edge which is not good when watching the candy thermometer to access the temperature.
Using the clip on candy thermometer seems misleading. Am I using it correctly? Should it only be used for smaller pots?

That is an accurate reading. It is not misleading. It’s a measurement of the temperature of the syrup, taken from near the edge of the pot.
It sounds like there’s a significant temperature gradient in your pot. This can happen with large batches, particularly if heated very quickly and if the burner is smaller than the pot, and if there’s little convection (say, if you’re not stirring well).
But again, that is the actual temperature of that part of the syrup. If you only try to get the middle of the pot to the target temperature, your results will not be good overall.

Also, if Dutch oven is made of cast iron, it will have poor thermal conductivity, possibly explaining the temperature gradient. I would try with a stainless steel pot with an aluminum core to see if it helps.

@Najkin No pot is going to have good enough thermal conductivity to directly keep its sides up to temperature. The difference between plain old cast iron and expensive fancy aluminium-core cookware would be in hot spots on the bottom, which there's no reason to believe are a problem in this case. Honestly, cast iron is nearly ideal here, but the choice of pot is not going to make a big difference as long as the burner is large enough.

So the advice for accurate use of the thermometer is essentially better temperature management of the candy? For example, stir the candy, use a burner that aligns with the pot etc?

Well, it’s not entirely clear that advice is needed here. Again, you do not have a problem with accuracy. If the candy you are making is coming out well then there’s nothing you need to do. If you find that the candy is burning or not achieving the proper consistency then you might consider those approaches.
